# Scheme - access variable in closure

Tags: lambda, scheme, closures, counter, let

Lets say I have the following closure in Scheme, that increases a counter everytime it's called:

```
 (define count
   (let ((next 0))
     (lambda ()
         (set! next (+ next 1))
         next)))
```

My question is simply, how can I re-write this function so I can access the value of `next` without incrementing the counter? I've tried playing around with lambdas, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Edit: some context:

```
(define (dispatch m)
    (let ((count 0))
        (cond ((eq? m 'withdraw) withdraw) ; Increments count
              ((eq? m 'deposit) deposit) ; Increments count
              ((eq? m 'balance) balance-return)
              ((eq? m 'transaction) count) ; "count" on this line should return the value
              (else (error "Unknown request -- MAKE-ACCOUNT"
                           m)))))
```

Comment: Could you give an example of code that uses the value of `next`?

Comment: Added to main question.

Comment: In the example you provided the inner `count` will always be returned (0 in this case), as you bind it with let. You have to change the definition of `count` inside the `dispatch` function. I imagine that this is what you'll do, but I'm not sure

Comment: Your question does not reproduce the problem you mention ( [[(dispatch 'transaction)]] = [[(count)]] despite what you say in your comment). This confuses the people searching for an answer to this or a similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear how the `count` is related to the bank account example, however something as simple as

```
(define (make-account)
    (let ((count 0)) ; Define `count` here...
        (define (dispatch m) ; ...and define `dispatch` such that `count` is in scope
            (cond ((eq? m 'next) ; On message 'next...
                   (lambda () (set! count (+ count 1)))) ; ...return the lambda, which has `count` in its scope
                  ((eq? m 'count) ; On message 'count...
                   count) ; ...return the current count
                  (else ; Otherwise...
                   (error "Unknown request -- MAKE-ACCOUNT" m)))) ...raise error
        dispatch)) ; Return `dispatch` from `make-account`
```

might be what you're looking for.

The main ideas being:

1. Create a scope in which your variable can live (here: the scope of the `make-account` procedure)
2. Create your variable in that scope (here: `(let ((count 0))`)
3. Just access it within the scope (here: setting or getting the `count`)
4. Return *something* that has the variable in scope (here: the `dispatch` closure).

You can then `(define acc-dispatch (make-account))`, and subsequently retrieve the current count using `(acc-dispatch 'count)`, but you could still increment it if you wanted, using `((acc-dispatch 'next))`.

Note that the latter *applies* the lambda returned by calling `(acc-dispatch 'next)`.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was where my `(let ((count 0))` was, it was in the incorrect scope. Putting it just under the main function definition achieved the results I wanted. Thanks :)